# how to replace string with object values

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, discord.js

I'm trying to replace the user flags with emojis but I have no idea how to do it.
I tried that but it didn't work

````
const flags = {
    "HOUSE_BRILLIANCE":"<:house_brilliance:773066280303198218>",
    "HOUSE_BRAVERY":"<:house_bravery:773066279967522868>",
    "HOUSE_BALANCE":"<:house_balance:773066280319057930>",
    "EARLY_SUPPORTER":"<:early_supporter:773066280416444466>",
    "HYPESQUAD_EVENTS":"<:hypesquad_events:773066279892418613>",
    "BUGHUNTER_LEVEL_1":"<:bughunter:773066280269512714>",
    "BUGHUNTER_LEVEL_2":"<:bughunter:773066280269512714>",
    "DISCORD_EMPLOYEE":"<:early_verified_bot_developer:773066280135688212>",
    "PARTNERED_SERVER_OWNER":"<:partnered_server_owner:773066279996751872>",
    "TEAM_USER":"",
    "SYSTEM":"",// tf is this one
  }
let mflags = message.mentions.users.first().flags.toArray().join(' ')
let fres = mflags.replace(/#(\w+)/g, (match,key)=>flags[key]||match);```
````

Comment: You said you "tried that" without mentioning what it is. Yes there's some code but it's not descript enough to understand the problem and what you're trying to achieve. Please edit the question and elaborate.

Comment: nvm I fixed it with a for loop

Comment: yea, you should just iterate through the flags as an array and then replace each entry with what you've mapped in the object